# π-backbonding in tungsten complexes

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

I need to find in which of the following complexes the M-CO bond is stonger:
[WO3(CO)3] and [W(CH3)3(CO)3].

According to my knowledge this is chiefly determined by the π-backbonding and how good donors or acceptors the present ligands are. CO is a great σ-donor as well as a decent π-acceptor while CH3- functions as a donor. Now apart from the final answer, I'm not sure about the oxygens. Is there a dioxygen ligand alongside with an oxo ligand? If that's the case I think the second compound would present a stronger M-CO bond since only the CO ligands can receive charge from the metallic centre. Is this approach correct?